# Call on an Async Task from main activity to a fragment

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, arcgis-runtime

I have an async task that needs to initilize on a button click inside my bottomsheet fragment. However when I call on the method from my bottomsheet fragment with

```
  private async void _navigationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {          
       await ((MainActivity)Activity).Routing();
   }
```

I get the error:

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'p' of 'MainActivity.Routing(MapPoint)' Maps.

The code below is my method for getting a route when clicking on a mappoint on the map in my mainactivity.

```
try
{
    _textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this, "com.google.android.tts");

    Stop stop0 = new Stop(_startPoint) { Name = "Starting Point" };
    // Stop stop1 = new Stop(_endPoint) { Name = "EndPoint" };

    if (_endPoint == null)
    {
        await _geocoder.ReverseGeocodeAsync(p);
        _endPoint = p;
        RouteTask routeTask = await RouteTask.CreateAsync(_routingUri);
        RouteParameters routingParameters = await routeTask.CreateDefaultParametersAsync();
        List<Stop> stops = new List<Stop> { new Stop(_startPoint), new Stop(_endPoint) };
        routingParameters.SetStops(stops);
        RouteResult result = await routeTask.SolveRouteAsync(routingParameters);

        Route firstRoute = result.Routes.First();

        _routeAheadGraphic = new Graphic(firstRoute.RouteGeometry) { Symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 4) };

        SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle.Dash, System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2) }; _myMapView.GraphicsOverlays[0].Graphics.Add(_routeAheadGraphic);

        await _myMapView.SetViewpointGeometryAsync(firstRoute.RouteGeometry, 100);

        return;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the MapPoint parameter in your call to Routing

Comment: How can i define the mappoint parameter in the fragment activity? Because the mappoint p, is defined in the main activity

Comment: I don't know ! This is your code - i'm just telling you what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mappoint is not available in Fragment, you could define a public method in Main activity first  , call `Routing(mapPoint)` inside that method .

#### Main Activity

```
 public void MyMethod(){
     Routing(mapPoint);
 }
```

#### Fragment

```
private async void _navigationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    await ((MainActivity)Activity).MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: Haven’t tried it yet, i’m out of town at the moment. Will try it out tomorrow or on sunday and Report back to you!

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It says "Error CS0119 'MapPoint' is a type, which is not valid in the given context" and the routing method is an async task.

Edit: I tried your solution by making the mappoint variable public and calling myMethod inside my fragment. However the routing task initialize before my _navigtationbutton_Click is executed.

Comment: I did not get you , what is the meaning of  `the routing task initialize before my _navigtationbutton_Click is executed.` ?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to solve it. The main problem was that the routegraphic was executed before i pressed the navigation button. I countered this by creating a new method for the routeaheadGraphic and called it from my fragment.

Comment: If my answer helps you could accept it as answer or you could post your solution and mark it.